# passing and manipulating data between a controller, directives, and a service --angularJS

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, controller, directive

My angular skills are not great and I have encountered a problem which has stalled my progress.

Initially I had a Main controller and 5 directives. The directives and the main controller were happily working together, by passing data to/from the main controller through scope. Until the 5th directive required the data from all the other directives to be computed. I tried passing the data from all the directives to the main controller and then passed it to the 5th directive. but unfortunately due to the asynchronous nature of both data and js it did not work i.e. it is not being updated in some parts of the code and i kept getting null. I tried putting a $watch even that did not work.

Upon recommendation of a colleague, I introduced a service to transfer data between the directives and controllers. So no I have a Main controller, few directives and a service.

The service loads data from the DB for each directive through multiple queries. and Each directive performs computations on their set of data. but still the same problem of data not being available / undefined at different points in code exists. I don't know what else to do. If anyone can suggest a solution that will be a massive help.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hi there. There's not really enough information to offer up a specific helpful solution as this question is currently written. I'd suggest checking out [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: There is too much code, so it is not possible to share the code here. but I will try to improve the question, by providing the details on the structure.

Comment: you can try initializing you directive variable to blank and then assign data to them as per your needs. Make sure that your directives handle empty conditions for all of required data/variables

Comment: I am trying to handle the conditions for empty/undefined values but another obstacle is that the $watch is not working properly for more than one variable. and even if the watch works the code just never gets past the condition sometimes. may be i think values form the services are not getting updated at that moment in time. for example. if i do $scope.data1 = service.data1; at that point in time service.data1 is undefined. How do I harmoniously manage the transfer and manipulation of data in my code.